# Lambda expression for multiple Guids

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Trying to create a Lambda expression to select records from a database containing any of seven Guid values.

When I try the following:

```
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAGuid && stageAPlusGuid && //etc);
```

I get an `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Guid'`, same for `||` (not sure which or if I should be using either of these operators)

If I try:

```
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAGuid);
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAPlusGuid);
```

Nothing returns

Does anybody can help me with this?

Comment: You must repeat the variable name. `searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => 1stageAGuid || s.STAGEID == stageAPlusGuid || //etc)`

Answer (score 7):

You could try this if you have some keys with `OR` operator, which in C# is `||`, for sample:

```
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAGuid 
                                    || s.STAGEID == stageAPlusGuid));
```

But, if you have a list of keys, you could try using the `Contains` method, for sample:

```
List<Guid> guids = /* get your keys from somewhere */;
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => guids .Contains(s.STAGEID));
```

If you are working with linq to database (linq-to-sql, entity-framework, nhibernate, etc.) it will generate a query with `IN` operator with all keys for you.

Answer (score 6):

In your second example, you're looking for objects with `STAGEID == stageAGuid` *AND* `STAGEID == stageAPlusGuid`. It's not surprising you don't get any results.

In your first example you just need to repeat the key you want to compare:

```
searchedOpps = searchedOpps
               .Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAGuid 
               || s.STAGEID == stageAPlusGuid [...]);
```

The way you wrote it, the compiler tries to get a `bool` by '`OR`ing' a `bool` (from the first comparison) and a `GUID` (the value after the `&&`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to "OR" your conditions and specify the comparison each time.

```
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAGuid || 
                                       s.STAGEID == stageAPlusGuid || //etc);
```

Note that consecutive calls to `Where` will "AND" the conditions together.

```
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAGuid);
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAPlusGuid);
```

is the same as

```
searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(s => s.STAGEID == stageAGuid && 
                                       s.STAGEID == stageAPlusGuid);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class:

```
var searchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Songs>();

searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(g=> g == stageAGuid);
searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(g=> g == stageAPlusGuid);

searchedOpps = searchedOpps.Where(searchPredicate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what system you're using for data access, so I'm going to assume it's EF and at least .NET 4.

If you write your query correctly, LINQ-to-Entities will translate it into a SQL "in" clause. Check out this MSDN entry:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx

If you have 7 different guids you're looking for, do something like this:

```
Guid[] myGuidList =
    { stageAGuid, stageAPlusGuid, anotherGuid, guid4, guid5, guid6, guid7, };

var results = searchedOpps.Where(s => myGuidList.Contains(s.STAGEID));
```

The resulting SQL will look like this:

```
select * from searchedOpps where STAGEID in (<guid>, <guid>, <guid>...)
```